# Forgot Authy password

Tags: security, 2fa

I accidentally broke my OnePlus 5 which contained the recovery codes for my Instagram and Facebook, both were using Authy as their two factor authenticator. Thing is I apparently don't remember my Authy backup password either, I've tried all my common passwords.

I logged into Authy on an old phone (Moto G5 Plus), I've tried all my common passwords, none of them seem to work.

There's no other way I can login to my Instagram. For Facebook they're asking for a government ID which I'm not comfortable providing. Authy is the only thing preventing me from accessing my Instagram and Facebook.

Is there any way I can brute force the password out of Authy on my phone? There's no desktop version or Firefox extension/add-on that I can use to login to unfortunately. Or is there any other method that I'm missing?

Any small help would be deeply appreciated. Thank you

Comment: no more access to Instagram or Facebook is probably the best thing ever happens to impact your real life ;)